# Using Javascript to parse file with regex and convert info into json

Tags: javascript, json, regex

How can I organize the following data format into JSON? The data is a simple text file that looks like:

```
<--Header Title-->
Some block of info here
<--Header Title-->
Some block of info here
<--Header Title-->
Some block of info here
```

There are some **tricky bits**, like:

a) Possible to contain `<--Header Title-->` inside the `Some block of info here`:

```
<--Header Title-->
I am info for <--Header Title-->
<--Header Title-->
This <--Header Title--> is finished
<--Header Title-->
<--Header Title--> contains the following:
stuff1
stuff2
stuff3
```

b) `Some block of info here` can either be empty or just whitespaces/newlines

```
<--Header Title-->
<--Header Title-->


<--Header Title-->
Info text here
```

c) `Some block of info here` format should be preserved, unless it's only whitespaces/newlines like in (b). So the following should preserve the leading and ending whitespaces/newlines:

```
<--Header Title-->

More info about blah

blah blah blah
blah blah

<--Header Title-->
Another info about blah
```

**All in all, I'd like to convert this into a json for easy retrieval.** A simple example:

```
<-- Option 1 -->
Nice text
<-- Option 2-->


<--Final stuff-->
Listing all
of
the
text

<--Header Title-->
I am info for <--Header Title-->
<--Header Title-->
This <--Header Title--> is finished
<--Header Title-->
<--Header Title--> contains the following:
stuff1
stuff2
stuff3
```

json:

```
{
  "data":
    [
        {"Option 1": "Nice text"},
        {"Option 2": ""},
        {"Final stuff": "Listing all\nof\nthe\ntext\n"},
        {"Header Title": "I am info for <--Header Title-->"},
        {"Header Title": "This <--Header Title--> is finished"},
        {"Header Title": "<--Header Title--> contains the following:\nstuff1\nstuff2\nstuff3"}
    ]
}
```

My current regex is:

```
\<\-\-(.*)\-\-\>\n(.*)
```

But this only captures the first occurrence, and only if (a) doesn't occur.

Comment: Anchor your pattern at the start of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex **[`/<--([\w\s]+)-->([\s\S]*?)(?=\n<--|$)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/cV5rL2/1)** and do something like this

```js
var str = `<-- Option 1 -->
Nice text
<-- Option 2-->


<--Final stuff-->
Listing all
of
the
text

<--Header Title-->
I am info for <--Header Title-->
<--Header Title-->
This <--Header Title--> is finished
<--Header Title-->
<--Header Title--> contains the following:
stuff1
stuff2
stuff3`;


var reg = /<--([\w\s]+)-->([\s\S]*?)(?=\n<--|$)/g,
  m,
  res = { // object to store result
    data: []
  };

while (m = reg.exec(str)) {
  var data = {};
  data[m[1].trim()] = m[2].trim(); // storing data into object after formating
  res.data.push(data); // pushing object to array
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

**[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/cV5rL2/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]